# Close activity from another activity through an intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to open an activity from the first one, and i want to close the first one with an intent. I tried this, but the receiver doesn't work. And i have different receivers in my application, so i want that this intent is received only from FirstReceiver. How can i do it?

```
public class First extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
        Intent close = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Close.class);
        startActivity(close);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.first, menu);
        return true;
    }

    class FirstReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            Log.e("FirstReceiver","FirstReceiver");
            First.this.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the second class.

```
public class Close extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_close);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent();
        sendBroadcast(myIntent);
        Log.e("onCreate","onCreate");
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.close, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just close the First activity when you start the second? You can call finish() after startIntent().

Comment: I know it, but i'd like to close it in that way.

Comment: "I'd like to" do it that way have no place in programming. Why do something way more complicated if you can do the simple text-book way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this may help you...

```
public class First extends Activity {
    public static final String ACTION_CLOSE = "yourPackageName.ACTION_CLOSE";
    private FirstReceiver firstReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_CLOSE);
        firstReceiver = new FirstReceiver();
        registerReceiver(firstReceiver, filter);
        Intent close = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Close.class);
        startActivity(close);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.first, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(firstReceiver);
    }

    class FirstReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.e("FirstReceiver", "FirstReceiver");
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_CLOSE)) {
                First.this.finish();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Close extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_close);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(First.ACTION_CLOSE);
        sendBroadcast(myIntent);
        Log.e("onCreate", "onCreate");
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.close, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: One last thing. I'd like to show something to the user before closing the application, but in the onreceive i can't show anything (leaked window that was originally added here) because it's too late. I must show this from First class. How can i do it?

Comment: If you want to show the user a `Dialog` before closing, then have the receiver call a method on the activity that shows the dialog. When the user clicks on "OK" or whatever buttons you have on the `Dialog`, you can `finish() the activity then.

Comment: @AsAs consider the solution given by David Wasser

Comment: You might want to unregister the BroadcastReceiver

Answer (score 2):

For it is better to Use startActivityForResult,onActivityRsult()

```
 Intent in = new   Intent(getApplicationContext(), Close.class);
 startActivityForResult(in, RESULT_CLOSE);
```

and override `onActivityResult` in your `Activity` and implement like this..

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  

super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);     

 if (requestCode == RESULT_CLOSE){

       finish();
     }
```

call the `setResult()` in Close activity when ever you want to close the your mainActivity..

Comment: Ok, but if make a change and i have a second class between the other two (First->Second->Close) it won't work anymore. I'd like to do it the way i asked if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

When the user wishes to exit all open activities, they should press a button which loads the first Activity that runs when your app starts, in my case "Close".

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Close.class);
intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

The above code clears all the activities except for **Close**. **Close** is the first activity that is brought up when the user runs the program. Then put this code inside the **Close**'s onCreate, to signal when it should self destruct when the 'Exit' message is passed.

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
    finish();
}
```